# Usage of class in PHP from different directory

Tags: php, class

I have been using Classes in PHP.

I have a directory, test, In which there is index.php
A sub-directory to test is new, which has checkuser.php
Code for checkuser CODE:

```
<?php
    public class checkuser{
            public function checkuser()
        {
            echo "This is class";   
        }   
        }
?>
```

Code for index.php:

```
<?php include('new/checkuser.php'); ?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php

            checkuser::checkuser();     
                ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

But It always throws error.
Please Help.

Comment: Kindly add the error message you are getting.

Comment: It should --->echo 'This is class' which it is not doing.

Comment: It's a logical error. Not a code syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error is that?

There is more things:

You are declaring the class "public"

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC on line 2
```

You are calling non-static method statically

```
Fatal error: Non-static method checkuser::checkuser() cannot be called statically on line 17
```

You are including the file, without being aware of the context, i suggest this practice:

```
<?php include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/new/checkuser.php'); ?>
```

or if you are using PHP > 5.3

```
<?php include( __DIR__ . '/new/checkuser.php'); ?>
```

And here is how your code could work:

```
<?php
class checkuser {
    public static function myfunction()
    {
        echo "This is class";   
    }   
}
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php checkuser::myfunction(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://codepad.org/C9boO1lI

Note: of course, you can split your code in more files, just make sure that you specify the path as seen above, so it can find the actual file